# The grammatical form of the sentence

Tags: verbs, nouns

```
“It was not a wolf,” Brienne heard herself say.
```

Is the "say" a verb and the phrase grammaticaly close to

```
Brienne heard that she say.
```

Or the "say" is an noun and the phrase closer to

```
Brienne heard her opinion.
```

Or is it something other?

Comment: "Say" is a verb. "It was not a wolf" is the main clause, and "Brienne heard herself say" is a parenthetical, a form of supplement.

Comment: What about "Brienne heard John say"? Is this construction grammaticaly differ from previous or not?

Comment: No, there's no difference in the basic structure. Note that in both examples, the NPs "herself" and "John" are the direct object of "heard", and the infinitival clause "say" is complement of "heard". I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It was not a wolf,” Brienne heard herself say.*

"Say" is a verb.

"It was not a wolf" is the main clause, and "Brienne heard herself say" is a parenthetical, a form of supplement.

Note that syntactically the noun phrase "herself" is the direct object of "heard", and semantically the *understood* subject of the infinitival "say" clause, functioning as complement of "heard".